# S3 key redirect changed from http to https causes key to be downloaded instead of redirect (python)

Tags: python, redirect, amazon-s3

I have a local script (BOTO using Python) that I use to create redirect objects (URL's) on S3.

I have implemented in a workflow I have for Safari on MacOS so that I can create shortlinks to complex URL's.

The script has been working fine on a bucket mapped to a sub domain of mine. I have then decided to move it to a bucket where I have a SSL certificate running.

But instead of redirecting the user visiting the redirect object to the destination URL, the browser downloads the object.

The only difference is that I have changed my script to point to a subdomain behind a certificate...

Should I do anything special to make the redirect objects work https protected sites?﻿

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have the same `Content-Type` (required) and `Content-Disposition` (optional) metadata set on the object now, as before?

Comment: Sry for the late reply. Only the certificate is the difference to the server, the original bucket is setup the same way as the new one. However I haven't had any time to dig deeper into the issue since posting the question.